# selecting a tor node from a particular country

Tags: configuration

This is of interest, and was asked earlier about Netflix, but I'd like to do this for a low-bandwidth application. That is, if I'm in the U.S., and I'd like the site I'm looking at to see that my request is from the U.S. If I were to use ExitNodes to do this, what would that .torrc line look like? On a Mac OS, where exactly does that .torrc file go?

Now, I understand that this would hugely constrain my available network, and wouldn't be advisable if I didn't have to do it, but I'd still like to understand how to do it. Sure would be nice if there were a more user-friendly way of selecting that option.

Comment: @Jobiwan  I should have directed the question here ... it looks like /opt/etc/.torrc isn't right for Mac OX 10.6. There isn't an /opt/etc. Now, when I do Settings->Advanced, it tells me that there is a torrc (not .torrc) in /USER/Library/Vidalia. Is that where the ExitNodes should go? Now, strangely, there is also a /USER/.tor directory. Is that relevant here?

Comment: I edited my original answer. I just tried this. You should edit torrc in Tor Browser/Library/Vidalia/ inside the Tor Browser package.

Comment: The question specifically mentions the alleged duplication and says why it is _not_ a duplicate of those.

Comment: if you install via homebrew, then the path to the torrc file is `/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc` and you can add the lines at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

torrc sits in /opt/etc/tor/

On Mac OS X, the torrc file is within the application.  For version 4.5.2, the path is **(path)/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc**  (So all users get the same settings, unless they have their own copy of the browser).  “New tor circuit” and “new identity” do not re-read the file—if you want to select a country in this way, you must edit then exit the browser and re-launch it.

The line would be:

```
ExitNodes node, node, ...
```

where *node* is.. (Quoted from [Tor Manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en))

> a list of identity fingerprints, nicknames, country codes and address
>   patterns. (Example:
>   ExcludeNodes SlowServer, ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234,
>   {cc}, 255.254.0.0/8)

The country code is {us}

Answer (score 0):

torrc file should have this lines:

```
ExitNodes {us}
StrictNodes 1
```